# Is this an even function?

Tags: calculus, functions

How to show that

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0, &|x|>2 \\ 
2x-1, & 1<|x|\leq 2\\ 
3-x &, |x|\leq 1 
\end{matrix}\right.$

is *even* function?

Thank you!

Comment: It isn't because $f(-x)=3+x\ne 3-x=f(x)$ for every $x \in [-1,0)\cup(0,1]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $1$ and $-1$ verify the condition $|x|\leq 1$ then their images are determined by the expression $3-x$, so $f(1)=2\neq f(-1)=4$, hence $f$ is'nt even.

You can also plot the curve of this function and check that it isn't symmetrical   according the ordinate axis.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To show that a function is even you must show that $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x$.  With a piecewise function you'll need to do this in parts.

1. Check that $f(x) = f(-x)$ when $|x| > 2$
2. Check that $f(x) = f(-x)$ when $1 < |x| \leq 2$
3. Check that $f(x) = f(-x)$ when $|x| \leq 1$

When you do the check you'll find that (1) holds but (2) and (3) do not, thus $f$ is not an even function.